# Sequentially combine arbitrary number of futures in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I'm new to scala and I try to combine several Futures in scala 2.10RC3. The `Futures` should be executed in sequential order. In the document [Scala SIP14](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html) the method `andThen` is defined in order to execute Futures in sequential order. I used this method to combine several `Futures` (see example below). My expectation was that it prints `6` but actually the result is `0`. What am I doing wrong here? I have two questions:

First, why is the result `0`. Second, how can I combine several `Futures`, so that the execution of the second `Future` does not start before the first `Future` has been finished.

```
val intList = List(1, 2, 3)

val sumOfIntFuture = intList.foldLeft(Future { 0 }) {
 case (future, i) => future andThen {
  case Success(result) => result + i 
  case Failure(e) => println(e)
 }
}

sumOfIntFuture onSuccess { case x => println(x) }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`andThen` is for side-effects. It allows you to specify some actions to do after future is completed and before it used for something else.

Use map:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).foldLeft(Future { 0 }) {
     |  case (future, i) => future map { _ + i }
     | } onSuccess { case x => println(x) }
6
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this generic approach:

```
trait FutureImplicits {

  class SeriallyPimp[T, V](futures: Seq[T]) {
    def serially(f: T => Future[V])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[V]] = {
      val buf = ListBuffer.empty[V]
      buf.sizeHint(futures.size)

      futures.foldLeft(Future.successful(buf)) { (previousFuture, next) =>
        for {
          previousResults <- previousFuture
          nextResult <- f(next)
        } yield previousResults += nextResult
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def toSeriallyPimp[T, V](xs: Seq[T]): SeriallyPimp[T, V] =
    new SeriallyPimp(xs)

}
```

Then mix-in the above trait and use it like this:

```
val elems: Seq[Elem] = ???
val save: Elem => Future[Result] = ???
val f: Future[Seq[Result]] = elems serially save
```

This code could be improved to preserve the input collection type. See [this](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/execute-scala-futures-in-serial-one-after-the-other-non-blocking/) article for example.