# Failing a Future based on a successful result

Tags: scala, future

I have a scenario in my code where I need to make a `Future` fail based on a successful result that contains a certain value.  I can make this work just fine via `flatMap`, but I want to know if there is a cleaner way to make this work.  First, a very simplified example:

```
import concurrent._

case class Result(successful:Boolean)
object FutureTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits._

    val f = Future{Result(false)}.flatMap{ result =>
      result match{
        case Result(false) => Promise.failed(new Exception("The call failed!!")).future
        case _ => Promise.successful(result).future
      }
    }

    f onFailure{
      case x => println(x.getMessage())
    }
  }
}
```

So in my example here, I want the `Future` to be failed if the `Result` returned has a value of `false` for its success indicator.  As I mentioned, I can make this work okay with `flatMap`, but the line of code I would like to eliminate is:

```
case _ => Promise.successful(result).future
```

This statement seems unnecessary.  The behavior that I would like is to be able to define the condition and if it evaluates to true, allow me to return a different `Future` as I am doing, but if it's not true, just leave things as they are (sort of like `PartialFunction` semantics.  Is there a way to do this that I'm just not seeing?  I've looked at `collect` and `transform` and those don't seem to be the right fit either.

**Edit**

After getting the `map` suggestion from @Rex Kerr and @senia, I created a `PimpedFuture` and an implicit conversion to pretty up the code a bit like so:

```
class PimpedFuture[T](f:Future[T])(implicit ex:ExecutionContext){
  def failWhen(pf:PartialFunction[T,Throwable]):Future[T] = {
    f map{
      case x if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) => throw pf(x)
      case x => x
    }
  }
}
```

The implicit

```
  implicit def futToPimpedFut[T](fut:Future[T])(implicit ec:ExecutionContext):PimpedFuture[T] = new PimpedFuture(fut)
```

And the new handling code:

```
val f = Future{ Result(false) } failWhen {
  case Result(false) => new Exception("The call failed!!")
}
```

I think this is a little cleaner while still utilizing the suggestion to use `map`.

Comment: You want *new* future in both cases? Or only in case of failure?

Comment: The result itself, in my actual code, is being returned from a call to an actor.  I don't want that actor to always propagate a failure upstream given this kind of result.  It's based on successfully storing a value into couchbase via a call to add a key.  No all calling code cares that the value of the success flag is false; it's situational.

Comment: Sounds like a [`filter`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L306) method.

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I only want a new future if my match condition is met.  If match is not met, leave the existing future alone.

Comment: @senia, I looked at `filter`.  The issue there is that if my predicate is not true then the resulting `Future` is failed with a `NoSuchElementException` and that is undesired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with less effort with `map`:

```
val f = Future{ Result(false) } map {
  case Result(false) => throw new Exception("The call failed!!")
  case x => x
}
```

but you still need to explicitly mention that you're passing the identity through.

Note that that you [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13836725/406435) use `andThen` in such cases. `andThen` is for side effects, not for changing the result (unlike the `Function1` method of the same name).

Comment: You should use `map`, not `andThen`.

Comment: This would work if only it didn't throw the exception all the way out and not then get to my `onFailure` callback.  When I run this, I get a stacktrace in the code execution, so that's not the desired effect.

Comment: I'm confused as to how `map` will work.  The `map` function will go from a successful result of type `A` to a successful result of type `B`.  I want to fail the future given a certain condition and that's why I had been using `flatMap`.  I'll be interested in seeing how `map` applies here.

Comment: @cmbaxter: In this case `B` and `A` is the same type. The result of `throw` is [`Nothing`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing) and `Nothing` is subtype of all types, so it's also subtype of `A`.

Comment: I don't love it, but I think it will work.  Now, who is actually responsible for this answer so I can credit the right person.  Rex Kerr submitted it but @senia suggested it and edited it.

Comment: @cmbaxter: There is only 1 answer here. SO is a wiki-resource, not a MMORPG.

Comment: @senia - I think it would have been cleaner to delete mine and add yours, but this works too.

Comment: @andreyne - Indeed.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a different solution (without stacktrace side effect as @cmbaxter mentioned)

```
val prom = Promise[Int]()
val f = future {
    1
}

f onComplete {
    case Success(i) if i < 5 => prom.failure(new RuntimeException("_ < 5"))
    case Success(x) => prom.success(x)
}

prom.future onComplete {
    case Success(s) => println(s"We cool '$s'")
    case Failure(th) => println(s"All failed, ${th.getMessage}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to call the `filter` method, as @senia mentioned in the comments.

```
Future { Result(false) }.filter(_.successful) // throws NoSuchElementException
```

If you want a different exception type, you can chain the call with `recoverWith`:

```
Future { Result(false) }.filter(_.successful).recoverWith {
  case _: NoSuchElementException => Future.failed(new Exception("The call failed!!"))
}
```